# C:url not appending jsessionid when cookies are disabled

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I tried:

```
<c:url value="/web/pclub/userprofile" var="test">
    <c:param name="userid" value="${user.id}"/>
</c:url>
${test}
```

But when I check the page with cookies disabled then the jsessionid is not appended.
Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Are you sure cookies *are* disabled?  How have you done that?

Comment: Added the site to my cookies exclusion list in firefox. And the JSessionID does get appended to my URL when I log in. (some default generated links outside of my control). And I can retrieve the session id using getRequestedSessionId

Answer (score 3):

The `jsessionid` is only appended when the cookies are disabled **and** when a session has been created on the server side (and thus the server side needs to notify the client about this somehow, for which a cookie would is the default approach). If no session has been created, then there's no point of appending the `jsessionid`.

Try adding the following line to top of your JSP, at least before the `<c:url>` line is called. It not only prints/debugs the session ID for you, but it also implicitly creates the session if not done yet.

```
${pageContext.session.id}
```

Do this for testing purposes only. If it works, then the cause of your problem is that there was just no means of a session. Just keep it as is. There's no need to unnecessarily create the session. For the case whenever there's as session and the browser doesn't support cookies, the `c:url` will work fine.

---

By the way, to verify if the cookies are indeed disabled, track the request headers by [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com). If there's no `Cookie` header in the request even though the server has set a `Set-Cookie` header in the response, then it means that the cookies are indeed disabled in the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I think BalusC is right, however to force creating a session on the server, you can add a directive page on the top of your JSP, like this:

```
<%@ page session="true" %>
```